# DataFrame constructor error when load data from JSON

Tags: pandas

DataFrame constructor error when load data from JSON

I got the following error when load JSON data into dataframe by `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

DataFrame constructor not properly called!

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    284                                          copy=False)
    285             else:
--> 286                 raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
    287 
    288         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Is think I read the data into dataframe on a wrong way,

What's the correct way to read it into dataframe.

## data

https://gist.github.com/poc7667/0e4cded9920f78f2de1c

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in lines 110 and 111 you have not escaped the backslash. When this is done

```
pd.read_json('data.json')
```

works just fine

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in general, but it will in this case because your JSON data can be mapped to a DataFrame (i.e. it is a dictionary where each item holds the same number of values and has no further nesting).

It uses dictionary comprehension and iterates over the items in the data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: v for k, v in data.iteritems()})
```

Comment: You didn't mention if your JSON data was a dictionary or a serialized string.  If the latter, then the pd.read_json() method  mentioned by Woody should work just fine.